# How to create RealmList<RealmList<Object>> in android

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to get a RealmList of RealmList from server (JSON) into realm object. I am getting

> error: Element type of RealmList must be a class implementing 'RealmModel' or one of the 'java.lang.String', 'byte[]', 'java.lang.Boolean', 'java.lang.Long', 'java.lang.Integer', 'java.lang.Short', 'java.lang.Byte', 'java.lang.Double', 'java.lang.Float', 'java.util.Date'.

```
{
 "facilities": [
{
  "facility_id": "1",
  "name": "Property Type",
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "Apartment",
      "icon": "apartment",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Condo",
      "icon": "condo",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Boat House",
      "icon": "boat",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Land",
      "icon": "land",
      "id": "4"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "facility_id": "2",
  "name": "Number of Rooms",
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "1 to 3 Rooms",
      "icon": "rooms",
      "id": "6"
    },
    {
      "name": "No Rooms",
      "icon": "no-room",
      "id": "7"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "facility_id": "3",
  "name": "Other facilities",
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "Swimming Pool",
      "icon": "swimming",
      "id": "10"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garden Area",
      "icon": "garden",
      "id": "11"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garage",
      "icon": "garage",
      "id": "12"
    }
  ]
}
],
 "exclusions": [
[
  {
    "facility_id": "1",
    "options_id": "4"
  },
  {
    "facility_id": "2",
    "options_id": "6"
  }
],
[
  {
    "facility_id": "1",
    "options_id": "3"
  },
  {
    "facility_id": "3",
    "options_id": "12"
  }
],
[
  {
    "facility_id": "2",
    "options_id": "7"
  },
  {
    "facility_id": "3",
    "options_id": "12"
  }
]
]
}
```

Comment: can you provide the part of code that cause this error ?

Comment: private RealmList<Facility> facilities; - I am able to parse this ,
private RealmList < RealmList <Exclusion>> exclusions; - This causes error

Comment: RealmList < RealmList <Exclusion>>  is incorrect, so why you need using it ? show you purpose and I can help you

Comment: I have edited my question with JSON string. I need to parse such data so I need to use RealmList < RealmList <Exclusion>>

Comment: I got it, try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
public class Exclusion extends RealmObject {
    private int facilityId;
    private int optionsId;
}

public class Exclusions extends RealmObject {
private RealmList<Exclusion> exclusions;
}
```

so now you can using  `RealmList<Exclusions> exclusionsRealmList` as Realm list, legal

hope this helps

Comment: This will work for one Exclusion array. The json can have n number of exclusion array which needs RealmList < RealmList <Exclusion>>

Comment: so I have Exclusions that content RealmList<Exclusion>, Its mean RealmList<Exclusions> ~ RealmList < RealmList <Exclusion>>

Comment: Yes, I understand. Whatever you call as "Exclusions" can also be n in numbers.

Comment: i am not understand why you said "This will work for one Exclusion array" ?

Comment: I have pasted my entire json. Please get me a way to parse it and store it in realm

Comment: You can always use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org to get your object into some parseable format

Answer (score 0):

Gianthran's answer is close, but you should also set up relations.

```
 public class Exclusion extends RealmObject {
     @Index
     private int facilityId;
     @Index
     private int optionsId;

     private Facility facility;

     private Option option;
 }
```

And

```
 public class Facility extends RealmObject {
      @LinkingObjects("facility")
      private final RealmResults<Exclusion> exclusions = null;
 }

 public class Option extends RealmObject {
      @LinkingObjects("option")
      private final RealmResults<Exclusion> exclusions = null;
 }
```

I don't think the `Exclusions` object is necessary, I'd expect that the table is already a collection in a way.